# How can I get Rchunks to render inside tcolorbox?

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown

I've created a reprex to show my problem, but I am having this same issue in a custom Rmd template I am crafting.

I would like to be able to include stylized code chunks and plot outputs inside of tcolorbox environments. For some reason. When I knit the Rmarkdown, it doesn't render the tcolorbox environment.

Here is my reprex .RMD:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["tcolorbox", "tikz"]
---
```{r, include=FALSE}
library(tidyverse)
```

\begin{tcolorbox}
```{r,results='asis', eval=F}
iris %>% 
  group_by(Species) %>% 
  summarise(mean = mean(Sepal.Length), 
            sd = sd(Sepal.Width))
```

```{r,results='asis'}
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colors = Species)) + 
  geom_point()
```
\end{tcolorbox}
````

Here is the resulting .pdf:

[image]

When I remove the Rchunks, the tcolorbox renders correctly. I opened up the intermediate .tex file to see what was going on and it looks like it's canceling out the tcolorbox with a `\textbackslash{}`

```
\textbackslash{}begin\{tcolorbox\}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\NormalTok{iris }\OperatorTok{%>%}\StringTok{ }
\StringTok{  }\KeywordTok{group_by}\NormalTok{(Species) }\OperatorTok{%>%}\StringTok{ }
\StringTok{  }\KeywordTok{summarise}\NormalTok{(}\DataTypeTok{mean =} \KeywordTok{mean}\NormalTok{(Sepal.Length), }
            \DataTypeTok{sd =} \KeywordTok{sd}\NormalTok{(Sepal.Width))}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\begin{Shaded}
\begin{Highlighting}[]
\KeywordTok{ggplot}\NormalTok{(iris, }\KeywordTok{aes}\NormalTok{(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, }\DataTypeTok{colors =}\NormalTok{ Species)) }\OperatorTok{+}\StringTok{ }
\StringTok{  }\KeywordTok{geom_point}\NormalTok{()}
\end{Highlighting}
\end{Shaded}

\includegraphics{Untitled1_files/figure-latex/unnamed-chunk-3-1.pdf}
\textbackslash{}end\{tcolorbox\}
```

Without the Rchunks, it looks fine:

```
\begin{tcolorbox}

\end{tcolorbox}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like this is impossible and is a Pandoc problem and not an Rmarkdown or knitr problem. I found a hacky solution here:

https://github.com/jgm/pandoc/issues/3145

You can by pass this by placing this in your template .tex file:

```
\let\Begin\begin
\let\End\end
```

Then in your Rmarkdown file you can do:

````
\Begin{tcolorbox}

    ```{r}
    *Rcode Here*
    ```
\End{tcolorbox}
````

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure why the chunk output doesn't go directly into the color box for you, but it appears to me that there are easy ways to include graphics in a color box.  Here, I create a PNG file and call it with the LaTex:

````
---
title: "Untitled"
output: 
  pdf_document:
    extra_dependencies: ["tcolorbox", "tikz"]
---
```{r, include=FALSE}
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

png("my_plot.png")
ggplot(iris, aes(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, colors = Species)) + 
  geom_point()
dev.off()

```

\tcbox{%
\includegraphics[width=5in, height=4in]{my_plot.png}}
````

Comment: Yes, the graphics appear nicely, but it seems that the code chunks prevent the TColorBox from being read by Pandoc as a valid command. I'm not quite sure why it's doing this. I think it comes down to what `knitr` is passing too Pandoc.

Comment: I get an error that suggests the chunk is being processed as inline R code - which it is not. So, I'm thinking it's the text box LaTex that prevents the code chunk from being processed.